# Loading ListViewItems Bitmaps causes crash

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

As the title says, loading bitmaps into TListViewItems causes ANDROID apps to crash. Works for iOS, but not for Android. Picture Paths are CORRECT. For simplicity sakes, you can just drop a TImage onto the form, and manually set one image to it, then try instead of going through a loop as I did, just set 
`LItem.bitmap := TImage1.Bitmap`. Is it something I am doing wrong? or can someone confirm this and possibly help me out with a work around for now.

Delphi XE7 Android

```
if MenuList.Items.Count=0 then  // load menu options + icons
  begin
    for i := 0 to Length(PicturePaths)-1 do
    begin
      LItem:=MenuList.Items.Add;
      LItem.Text := PictureNames[i];
      LItem.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(TPath.GetHomePath+PathDelim+PicturePaths[i]);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Did you check the resulting filename? BTW you should use `TPath.Combine( TPath.GetHomePath, PicturePaths [i] )` because it is safe on all platforms.

Comment: Yes I did. And as I noted, even setting image from another image that is already displayed on the form doesn't work. I have this code snipped in the 'onShow' method of this form and it causes app to hang, but when I try to set iamges of listitem from an event after form is already shown, such as an click event, then it just doesn't do anything - no bitmap set. I will try using TPath.Combine now

Comment: Ok, i got the "bug" and updated my answer :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This happens if the [`TListView.ItemAppearance.Item.Appearance`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.ListView.TCustomListView.TPublishedAppearance.ItemAppearance) is not set to one of the options starting with `ImageListItem`. In this situation the Bitmap property is not assigned.

Since XE7 it is possible to have different settings for the controls for different devices. So it is possible to have set `ImageListItem` and for any other device `ListItem` and you will get the exception.

---

Code used in sample project:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click( Sender: TObject );
var
  LItem: TListViewItem;
  LImageFilename: string;
begin
  LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;

  LImageFilename := TPath.Combine( TPath.GetHomePath, 'sample.png' );
  LItem.Text := LImageFilename;
  // just be sure that the file exists and the bitmap is assigned
  if TFile.Exists( LImageFilename ) and Assigned( LItem.Bitmap )
  then
    LItem.Bitmap.LoadFromFile( LImageFilename );
end;
```

[Link to complete project source and compiled apk](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1wvqiwkzucunlat/AACMAZB8DFYfSggUIHpdiyGRa?dl=0)

Comment: Just to be clear for anyone else; your code is functionally equivalent, but you just added a couple lines of sanity-checking code, right?

Comment: To confirm - this worked on an actual Android Device? It works for me in iOS

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yes, this just contains some checking if the file is found and the bitmap is assigned. But in the end I see the text and the image as expected

Comment: Tested on Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 (SM-P605) with Android 4.4.2